# How to return multiple values to Switch?

Tags: php, switch-statement, categories, categorization

How can I return more than one value using `switch` in PHP?

In the example below, I'm trying to return **category1, category2, category3** for **product1**, but with the code below the `switch` statement only returns one value.

```php
switch ($product) {
    case "product1":
        $category = "category1";
        break;
    case "product1":
    case "product2":
        $category = "category2";
        break;
    case "product1":
    case "product2":
    case "product3":
        $category = "category3";
        break;
}
```

Is there a way to add multiple values to `$category`? And I would like to have the values separated by a comma, so I can use them as tags later on.

Comment: In case of `"product1"`, `$category` is set to be `"category1"` and then break. That's why the two latter cases are ignored. Why would you set a variable three times in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

You should use an array if you want to return multiple values.

```php
// We're going to store or multiple categories into an array.
$categories = array();
switch ($product) {
    case "product1":
        $categories[] = "category1";
        // This case label doesn't have a break statement, and thus it 'falls through'
        // to the next case label, which is "product2". That code block will also be
        // executed.
    case "product2":
        $categories[] = "category2"
    case "product3":
        $categories[] = "category3";
}
```

This snippet omits `break`s at the end of the case code blocks, thus it uses [switch case fallthrough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Fallthrough): if `$product == "product1"`, then the matching case label will be executed, but 'falls through' to the label `product2`, which will also be executed, and so on.

If `$product == "product1"`, then `$category` is an array with the values `category1`, `category2` and `category3`.

Then you can concatenate the strings in the array, separated with a comma, like this:

```php
echo implode(",", $categories);
```

*Notice: Sometimes, it's useful to use case fall through, but be advised, it is prone to errors. If your fallthrough is intended, then it is strongly recommended that you add a comment to notify other programmers that this fallthrough is intentional. Otherwise, they might think that you accidentally forgot the `break` statement.*

Comment: They probably should be in reverse order. The OP wanted categories 1, 2 and 3 for product 1, categories 2 and 3 for product 2, and so on.

Comment: For some reason it returns "Array" instead of the values i'm trying to get.

Comment: @user3011135 That's right, because when you try to echo a variable with the `array` data type, it prints array. You can format your array (display it as string) depending on what you want. Do you want it to be comma-separated? Then `implode(",", $array);` will do.

Comment: I don't understand why don't we need to have the "product1" to the cases 2 and 3, also why don't we use the break;

Comment: Both of those questions are addressed in this answer.

Comment: I found here, thanks guys. But i changed the script slightly to reflect more the structure that i'm actually going to use and it won't return the right values. have a look http://codepad.viper-7.com/PgLhCm

Comment: Since the categories of the products do not have a pattern (you cannot predict which product does have which category), the abovementioned method is not suitable to achieve what you want. You better switch over the products and assign multiple values in an array. Maybe this is what you want: http://codepad.viper-7.com/8oWivH.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with following.

```
$category = array();
switch($product)
{

case "product1":
  $category[] = "category1";

case "product2":
  $category[] = "category2";

case "product3":
  $category[] = "category3";
}
return implode(',',$category);
```

by appending the string and removing break statement will allow you to check all possible cases in switch.

Comment: You would have a `,` in the beginning which shouldn't be there. Correct way would be to use an array and then `join` the string together when needed.

Comment: The additional cases for `product1` and `product2` are not needed here. For example, in the case of `product1` we start at the top and "fall through" the rest.